# Philae - organic molecules?

Tags: rosetta, philae

Soon after the Philae landing on the comet Churyumov - Gerasimenko, there were news that it detected organic molecules on the surface. Does anybody know which ones? Were they the basic ones, like CO, that are so common in the universe? If so, of what interest is it to mankind?

Comment: (except pure awesomeness of the entire mission of course)

Comment: Related question: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6021

Comment: @ForgeMonkey Thank you, I missed this page.

Answer (score 5):

[Ptolemy instrument](http://rosettaptolemy.com/) sniffed water and 'organic' molecules before hibernation.

[image]
(source: [ESA](http://blogs.esa.int/rosetta/2014/12/02/the-quest-for-organic-molecules-on-the-surface-of-67pc-g/))

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_compound):

> An organic compound is any member of a large class of gaseous, liquid,
>   or solid chemical compounds whose molecules contain carbon.

Exact composition of Ptolemy detected organic molecules has not yet been announced, and according to some recent explanations such as during the [2014 AGU Fall Meeting Rosetta Comet Science Results](http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/56575467), the team is still working on identifying precisely which molecules were detected. That on its own means there's a good chance that all this excitement surrounding Ptolemy findings isn't merely about simple carbon compounds such as carbon oxides, and perhaps even less likely because [Rosetta's VIRTIS instrument](http://www.ifsi-roma.inaf.it/virtis/) already detected presence of carbon dioxide in comet's coma before the Philae lander even departed it:

[image]

Image source: [ESA TV exchange FTP site](http://tvdownload.esa.int/Philae%20Landing%2012%20Nov%202014/Still%20images/), shared Nov. 9, 2014 (Philae detached from Rosetta on Nov. 12, 2014)

Comment: Science journal just published [several reports](http://www.sciencemag.org/site/special/rosetta/) from the Rosetta / VIRTIS, including [The organic-rich surface of comet 67P/Churyumov-Gerasimenko as seen by VIRTIS/Rosetta](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/347/6220/aaa0628.full), detecting aliphatic tholins and aromatic hydrocarbons. Also on [Nature](http://www.nature.com/news/science-pours-in-from-rosetta-comet-mission-1.16777) ;)

Comment: On ESA site: [VIRTIS 67P/C-G rich in organics](http://blogs.esa.int/rosetta/2015/01/23/extremely-dark-dry-and-rich-in-organics-virtis-view-of-67pc-g/). `Another interesting result based on these infrared observations concerns the discovery of macromolecular organic compounds over the entire surface of the comet's nucleus. Some of these compounds are similar to the carboxylic acids.`